# How to add .fsh/.vsh shader files to Xcode so they are added to Copy Bundle Resources phase automatically?

Tags: xcode4, resources, bundle, shader

Whenever I add a new .fsh or .vsh OpenGL ES 2.0 shader file to my project's resources, the file is added to the Compile Sources build phase where it doesn't belong. I then have to manually remove it from that phase, and manually add it to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

Is there any way I can tell Xcode to add files with the extension .fsh and .vsh automatically to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase?

Or is it possible to create a Build Rule that has the same effect as adding the shaders to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase?

I would prefer a solution that works for all users of the Xcode project/workspace, rather than a setting or system change each Xcode user would have to play individually.

Comment: I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but my Spider Sense is telling me that the answer possibly lies in the "Build Rules" section of your project.

Comment: I thought so too but no luck there. Either I get "multiple build commands" or "no rule to process file" warnings. The most logical solution with a rule "GLSL source files using PBXCp" did not work, even if I set the fsh/vsh files' File Type to OpenGL Shading Language source.

Comment: I have a self-made graphics library that I share between projects. I would like to have the code and shaders in one folder, and have Xcode figure out which are source files and which are resources every time I import the library to a new project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My workaround is that I go to *File > New File > Others > Empty* files and name them as **shader.vertsh** and **shader.fragsh**.

I guess Xcode automatically adds files with dot 3/4 extensions to compile phase.

And in case you're missing the Syntax Highlighting, change the File type to 'OpenGL Shading Language Source':
[image: Xcode change file type]

Comment: this did not work for me, and I wouldn't want to e.g. rename existing source files just for this case.  I used the method of put-them-in-a-folder and add-to-project-via-folder-reference, mentioned by LearnCocos2D.

Comment: @jd. Yes I too wouldn't care to rename all existing code, this workaround is only good if you're starting a new project, also I hope Apple fixes this issue as in their sample code they've used the .vsh and .fsh extensions and everybody would love to follow that, including me :)

Comment: Don't think this fix is necessary any more, on XCode 5.1.1 `.vsh` and `.fsh` files are automatically added to `Copy Bundle Resources`

Comment: @aledalgrande You're right. I'm quite surprised that Apple hasn't provided a template file for shaders yet.

Answer (score 9):

Following is a workaround I found. If anyone has any other solutions I'd still appreciate the answer.

What you do to get the shaders into the **Copy Bundle Resources** build phase automatically is simply to put all the shaders in a common folder (or folder tree). I named the folder "Shaders". Then when adding the Shaders folder select **Create folder references for any added folders**.

As folder references the files are automatically assumed to be Bundle Resources by Xcode. You just need to be careful not to place any unwanted files into that folder respectively clean up the folder before making a release build. Also loading the shaders requires to use the path to the shader files, ie "Shaders/Examples/Blur.fsh".